# Call method in MainActivity from SubActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm calling a SubActivity from my MainActivity and in that SubActivity I have to call a method in my MainActivity. If I do that by using

```
MainActivity test = new MainActivity();
...
test.method("test");
```

I get a fatal exeption "Unable to start activity" NullPointerException.

I also tried `MainActivity.method("test")` but that also doesn't work. Changing a variable in the MainActivity works, by `MainActivity.booleanVariable = true;`

What could cause the NullPointerException? Do I miss something basical I'm too blind for right now?

Comment: How method looks like?

Comment: If you want to use method on another activity,you should know about intents or at least static references.

Comment: @R.id.pandacoder  Never make a static reference to an Activity.  Stairway to memory leaks.

Comment: You should not use `new` to create activities.  Only use `Intent`.  Put common code into custom classes.

Comment: I know about intents, i tried putExtra in the SubActivity, catching it with onActivityResult in my MainActivity, but I didn't understand the poor examples I found on web. That a static reference shouldn't be used is what I found out by googling

Comment: @Simon I know about memory leaks & classloaders for this situation. I guess autor don't know about it.

Comment: You should use `Intent` with extras to pass data to an `Activity` and `startActivityForResult()` in combination with `setResult()` to get a result back.  If you have problems with this, then ask a new question.  Do not try to find another technique because you couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never instantiate an `Activity` like this

```
MainActivity test = new MainActivity();
```

use an `Intent` to call an `Activity`. Now...

> I'm calling a SubActivity from my MainActivity and in that SubActivity I have to call a method in my MainActivity.

If it is a sub-`Activity` then that means it `extends MainActivity`. If this is the case then you can just do something like

```
@Override
public returnType myMethod(params)  // where returnType is int, boolean, void etc...
                                    // and params are parameters the method takes (if any)
{
    super.myMethod(params);
    // other code if needed
}
```

If the sub `Activity` doesn't `extends MainActivity` then please elaborate on why you *need* to do this and we can help find a better way.

**Edit**

From reading a comment of yours ("...catching it with onActivityResult in my MainActivity") above I think you are confused on how `startActivityForResult()` works and it can be tricky at first. If you call

```
Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
// put extras if needed
starActivityForResult(i);
```

in your second `Activity` then `onActivityResult()` will also go in your second `Activity`. It will be called from `FirstActivity` when you call `setResult()` there.

Comment: Hm after reading through some articles I think, SubActivity isn't right, it's just another activity, so lets better call it SecondActivity.. working with intents, I have already the "onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)" with switch/case-construct, but where to put the "putExtra", when I want to fire putExtras on different points in my SecondActivity?

Comment: I'm a bit confused but you use the `putExtra()`s after you create the `Intent` and generally before you call `startActivityForResult()`. You can add the `extra` at any point after you have instantiated the `Intent` but it won't be sent until you call one of the `startActivity()` methods.

Comment: @user2808184 I have made a short edit about using that. Maybe that can help some

Comment: but I'm a bit worried, that if I start my MainActivity via Intents every time I want to use the method in the MainActivity, it'll cause other problems?

Comment: I don't know what problems you would cause. You start the `Activity` to get a result then you finish that `Activity`...no big deal. If its  a method that you use in multiple `Activities` then you may consider what I explained in my answer and extend it in other Acitivities

Comment: Ok, I tried it out, but now my SecondActivity (which contents a setContentView) is never shown. I'm starting the MainActivity with startActivityForResult in the onCreate of SecondActivity, getting no Error (but without SecondActivity's View showing up)

Comment: You would need to post the code you are using. Most likely you aren't calling `setResult()` in your `MainActivity` (or at least not correctly)

Comment: `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case TOAST_REQUESTED:
    Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK);
break;` ...

Comment: Read my edit about how it works, my friend. `setResult()` is called in the `MainActivity` which is what returns to `onActivityResult()` in second `Activity`

Comment: I think I have to read much about Intents, I coded a lot in Java already but I've never had to use Activities because just coding little code-pieces.. Although, thanks for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. You will get it...just find a good tutorial to go through or just start out doing the most basic things. Also, you can find a lot of good examples of nearly anything Android here on SO. When you get stuck again, post a new question with a good explanation of your objective and current problem with the most relevant code snippets. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In **MainActivity** in `onCreate`(for example):

```
SecondActivity second = new SecondActivity();
second.test("Hello second");
```

in **SecondActivity** :

```
class SecondActivity extends Activity
{
   public static void test(String term)
   {
      Log.d("SecondActivity",term);
   }
}
```

## BUT!

***I strongly suggest that you refrain from this approach in real-world projects. And for the test - will do.***

For the best way you must use Intents, **or use callbacks** (Google it for this)

Example :

```
class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState);
      Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("hi","Hello world!");
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}

class SecondActivity extends Activity
{
   public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState);
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      Bundle temp = getIntent().getBundle();
      Lod.d("SecondActivity",temp.getStringExtra("hi","UNDEFINED") +"");
   }
}
```

You must declared both activities in Manifest. I think i give you start point for prolongation.

Comment: You shouldn't even test this.  The rule is simple.  Never try to access anything in one activity from another.  Using static methods in activities is wrong.  Very wrong.

Comment: I will repeat to you a second time. I know about static variables and the consequences of their use.

Comment: So why even suggest to a noob?

Comment: I see a level of answer, so don't make a holy war :)